# Wordpress - author dropdown / screen options not showing in admin - workaround needed

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, admin

I have inherited a wordpress website and the admin panel seems to be a little messed up.  There is no 'Author' dropdown on the posts admin pages.  Normally you would select this in the 'screen option' so it displays but this is not working.

Is there a setting in the database that I can set to display the author dropdown or is there another workaround so that I can have this feature?

See attached images for features missing.

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED:**

One possibility is that your theme (probably in functions.php) removed that feature, something like:

```
remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'author' );
```

If you can't find it, try adding it by doing something like:

```
function wpcodex_add_author_support_for_posts() {
    add_post_type_support( 'post', 'author' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_author_support_for_posts' );
```

Comment: no thats not in there.  There hasn't been much customisation to the theme.  Is there a similar function to add the authordiv?

Comment: Not sure what else it could be. Maybe there a plugin installed that would do that?

Comment: Or switch to default WordPress theme. Would that fix the issue?